# Using Django-postman tags in other html pages

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

SO far I've installed django-postman and it works so fine and successfully updated the default template just fine but now i want to use the django-postman tags in someother pages such as the navbar ... but i can't get it to work

here is a look at my

```
<li class="dropdown messages-menu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            <span class="label label-success">4</span>
          </a> 
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
            <li>
              <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
              <ul class="menu">
                <li><!-- start message -->
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                      <img src="{{ user.user.photo.url }}" class="img-circle" alt="User photo">
                    </div>

                     {% block pm_sender_cell %}   <h4 class="mailbox-name">{{ message.obfuscated_sender|or_me:user }}{% if message.count %} ({{ message.count }}){% endif %}</h4>{% endblock %}
                      <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 min</small>

                    <p>Message Excerpt</p>
                  </a>
                </li><!-- end message -->
                ...
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

my question is how can i make django-postman tags work on all my pages not only in /messages/inbox